# How to add shortcut for YcmCompleter RefactorRename?

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

I could find plenty of examples how to implement shortcuts for other YouCompleteMe functions, but this one takes a parameter, and I just couldn't find anything that resembles it.

What I want to do is this: when I press `<leader> rn`, a text input would appear that contains current name of the symbol I want to refactor, then I would edit it, press enter and vim would run command `YcmCompleter RefactorRename <new name>`

How do I do this in vim?

**UPDATE**
I've searched for example of what I want to do and found [this one](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/issues/3906).
Here is my current mapping:

`nmap <leader>yrn :exe 'YcmCompleter RefactorRename '.input('refactor \"'.expand('<cword>').'\" to:')<cr>"`

Problem is - when I use it, I get error: `RuntimeError: Cannot rename the symbol under cursor.`. This problem is not present when typing `RefactorRename`

Comment: See `:help input()` and `:help :execute`. YCM is a red herring, here.

Comment: @romainl See update